# Why is my loop not continuing properly in my rock paper scissors game?

Tags: bash, scripting, games

I'm making a bo3 rock paper scissors game. So far I've gotten it to work under every condition except ties. When a tie happens, it's meant to 'remake' that game by just subtracting 1 from I. It doesn't seem to be working however, and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, paper beats rock, 
userwin=0
compwin=0

printf "Welcome to rock paper scissors. "

for i in {1..3}
do
    printf "Type 'r', 'p', or 's': "

    #get users selection
    read user

    #detect input and assign it to a num that will be used to check against computer.
    if [[ $user == [rR] || $user == "Rock" || $user == "rock" ]]
      then
        user="r"
    elif [[ $user == [sS] || $user == "scissors" || $user == "Scissors" ]]
      then
        user="s"
    elif [[ $user == [pP] || $user == "paper" || $user == "Paper" ]]
      then
        user="p"
    else
        printf "Not a valid submission, you entered: %s\n" "$user"
    fi

   #get random number between 1 and 9
   comp=$(shuf -i 1-9 -n 1)

   #detect what number it was and assign either r p s to it. 
   if ((1<=comp && comp<=3))
     then 
       comp="r"
       printf "Computer chooses rock\n"
   elif ((4<=comp && comp<=6))
     then
       comp="s"
       printf "Computer chooses scissors\n"
   elif ((6<=comp && comp<=9))
     then
       comp="p"
       printf "Computer chooses paper\n"
   else
       printf "not in range?"
   fi

   #find out who won
   if [[ $user == "$comp" ]]
     then
        i=$((i-1))
        printf "It's a tie, remake!\n"
   elif [[ $user == "r" && $comp == "p" ]]
     then
       printf "You lose!\n"
       compwin=$((compwin+1))
   elif [[ $user == "p" && $comp == "r" ]]
     then  
       printf "You win!\n"
       userwin=$((userwin+1))
   elif [[ $user == "s" && $comp == "r" ]]
     then  
       printf "You lose!\n"
       compwin=$((compwin+1))
   elif [[ $user == "r" && $comp == "s" ]]
     then  
       printf "You win!\n"
       userwin=$((userwin+1))
   elif [[ $user == "p" && $comp == "s" ]]
     then  
       printf "You lose!\n"
       compwin=$((compwin+1))
   elif [[ $user == "s" && $comp == "p" ]]
     then  
       printf "You win!\n"
   else
       printf "something is borked"
   fi

   if [[ $userwin == 2 ]]
     then
       printf "You win the bo3!\n"
       break
   elif [[ $compwin == 2 ]]
     then
       printf "You lose the bo3!\n"    
       break
   else
      reali=$((i+1))
      printf "\nGame %s start\n" "$reali"
   fi

done
```

And here is an example of a failed game:

```
noah: [~/myFiles/scripts] ./rps.sh
Welcome to rock paper scissors. Type 'r', 'p', or 's': r
Computer chooses rock
It's a tie, remake!

Game 1 start
Type 'r', 'p', or 's': r
Computer chooses paper
You lose!

Game 3 start
Type 'r', 'p', or 's': r
Computer chooses scissors
You win!

Game 4 start
noah: [~/myFiles/scripts]
```

It seems something is messing with my I integer, but even with bash -x I can't figure out why. Can someone more experienced check it out?

Comment: `for` cycle in this for is enumeration of the values 1, 2, 3 and not counted loop as we can be used to from `C`. You can not modify the variable inside the cycle in bash, afaik. You should better go with endless loop and some break when your reach the number you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not modify the variable inside the `for` cycle like this in `bash`. Oh ... you can, but it will not affect the iterations. It is not counted loop as we can be used to from C.

Minimal example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}
do
    echo $i
    i=$((i-1))
    echo $i
done
```

obviously prints:

```
./b.sh 
1
0
2
1
3
2
```

You would better be with standard loop with condition (as proposed by Kusalananda):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while ((i++ < 3)); do
    echo $i
    # your code here
    #i=$((i-1))
    #echo $i
done
```

Leaving also the old proposal below, but the above is clearly better.

---

You would be better with infinite loop and take care of your own variable inside, if you want to modify the amount of runs. Something like this should do the job (in example increment of 2, otherwise it would never end):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while true; do
    if [[ $i > "3" ]]; then
        break
    fi
    echo $i
    i=$((i-1))
    echo $i

    i=$((i+2))
done
```

Comment: `while (( i++ < 3 ))` is another possibility.

Comment: It would be even more clear. Thank you for the note.

Comment: Thank you, this is good information. I'll start trying to migrate over to while now.

Comment: It is not that you should use `while` always. For fixed number of iterations, you can do better with `for`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Using a while loop allows us to do things like this though, which is great.